# Looking for a message queue can be used for nodejs and elixir

Tags: node.js, elixir, message-queue

I am looking for a message queue which can be used between nodejs and elixir. I know there are many queues support for nodejs but it is hard to find out one which provides API for both of these two languages. Does anyone know any implementation supports them? I want a open source solution for that.

Comment: Recommendations like this are off-topic for Stack Overflow because they're primarily opinion-based. Also, most actual message queues are theoretically language-agnostic and support, such as it is, is from third-party projects rather than the actual project itself. Your best bet is to pick a few and try to find libraries supporting them in those languages. Depending on how simple they are, it may also be practical to roll your own integration.

Comment: [NSQ](http://nsq.io/)

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ is a reasonable choice, it can be run locally (or in docker) and supports many languages http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html